# Grep not as a regular expression

Tags: linux, grep

I need to search for a PHP variable `$someVar`. However, Grep thinks that I am trying to run a regex and is complaining:

```
$ grep -ir "Something Here" * | grep $someVar
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
$ grep -ir "Something Here" * | grep "$someVar"
<<Here it returns all rows with "someVar", not only those with "$someVar">>
```

I don't see an option for telling grep *not* to interpret the string as a regex, but to include the `$` as just another string character.

Comment: In this question, the main issue is not about `grep` interpreting `$` as a regex. It's about the shell substituting `$someVar` with the value of the environment variable `someVar`, likely the empty string. The second example should not return all rows with `someVar` but all lines, because the empty string is in all lines. To tell the shell to not substitute, you have to use `'$someVar'` or `\$someVar`. Then you'll have to deal with the `grep` interpretation of the `$` character.

Comment: @ChristopheDrevet-Droguet: Thank you for the explanation, I was puzzled as to the downvote! Your comment is informative enough to be an answer, in fact it would be one of the better answers on the page if so.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Escape the `$` by putting a `\` in front of it.

Comment: This answer would have been much better if you took time to explain that the real issue with `$` is shell variable substitution which has nothing to do with `grep`.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The other answers already do a great job of explaining. I don't see what I could add by modifying my own answer.

Answer (score 361):

Use `fgrep` (deprecated), `grep -F` or `grep --fixed-strings`, to make it treat the pattern as a list of fixed strings, instead of a regex.

For reference, the documentation mentions (excerpts):

> `-F` `--fixed-strings` Interpret the pattern as a list of fixed
>   strings (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, any
>   of which is to be matched. (-F is specified by POSIX.)
>
> `fgrep` is the same as `grep -F`. Direct invocation as fgrep is
>   deprecated, but is provided to allow historical applications that rely
>   on them to run unmodified.

For the complete reference, check:
https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html

Comment: Agreed—when you're using variables you can't do something like PHP's `addslashes()` to it in bash. This is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Reminder: if using double quotes, you will still have to **escape the `$`**, e.g.: `grep -FR "unset(\$foo['bar'])"`, otherwise it thinks it's an external variable and tries to expand it

Comment: How do I separate the strings with a newline?

Answer (score 73):

`grep -F` is a standard way to tell `grep` to interpret argument as a fixed string, not a pattern.

Comment: Nice answer. It solved my issue when I search a string with $  using ssh command.  Escaping with "\" didn't work in that scenario. But -F flag did the trick.

Answer (score 10):

You have to tell grep you use a fixed-string, instead of a pattern, using '-F' :

```
grep -ir "Something Here" * | grep -F \$somevar
```

Answer (score 7):

In this question, the main issue is not about `grep` interpreting `$` as a regex. It's about the shell substituting `$someVar` with the value of the environment variable `someVar`, likely the empty string.

So in the first example, it's like calling `grep` without any argument, and that's why it gives you a `usage` output. The second example should not return all rows containing `someVar` but all lines, because the empty string is in all lines.

To tell the shell to not substitute, you have to use `'$someVar'` or `\$someVar`. Then you'll have to deal with the grep interpretation of the `$` character, hence the `grep -F` option given in many other answers.

So one valid answer would be:

```
grep -ir "Something Here" * | grep '$someVar'
```

Answer (score 3):

+1 for the `-F` option, it shall be the accepted answer.
Also, I had a "strange" behaviour while searching for the `-I..` pattern in my files, as the `-I` was considered as an option of `grep` ; to avoid such kind of errors, we can explicitly specify the end of the arguments of the command using `--`.

Example:

```
grep -HnrF -- <pattern> <files>
```

Hope that'll help someone.

Comment: what F stands for?

Comment: From http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html : "-F : Interpret the pattern as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched. (-F is specified by POSIX.)"

Comment: If `--` is used, can `-HnrF` be omitted?

Comment: @Daniel It depends on what you want to do : `-F` avoids interpreting the pattern as a regular expression, whereas `--` avoids interpreting elements following it as options of grep.

Comment: @AloïkéGo Thanks, I get it.